# Can O(3^log n) be rewritten as O(n^log 3)?

Tags: algorithm

Can time complexity of O(3<sup>log n</sup>) be equal to or rewritten as  O(n<sup>log 3</sup>)? Here, logarithmic base is 2.

Comment: [Both functions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3^log_k+n-n^log_k+3) are equivalent, so yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes

The reason is simple, as surprising as it may look, both functions are equals. Let's use the following notation:

- `ln(x)` is the natural logarithm
- `log(x)` is the logarithm in base 2

The proof:

As we know, `ln(a^b) = b*ln(a)` and `log(x) = ln(x)/ln(2)`. We apply these formulas to both functions:

- `ln(3^log(n)) = log(n)*ln(3) = ln(n)*ln(3)/ln(2)`
- `ln(n^log(3)) = log(3)*ln(n) = ln(3)*ln(n)/ln(2)`

The logarithm of both functions are equal and this proves that both functions are equal.

Comment: You can simplify this argument by just using the well know identity `a^log(b) == b^log(a)`, where `log` can have any base.